# Count number of visits before a user purchases. (Count should be reset after every purchase) in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table of events which records actions the customer takes in our website. I want to find out how many times a customer visited before he finally purchases an item.

[image]

The above table will be aggregated as
[image]

In the first week customerid 1 made 3 visits (including the visit in which he made a purchase). Again he made a purchase in the same week in another visit. So you can see 3 in the first case and 1 in second case. That is every time the user makes a purchase the count should be reset.

The solution i came up with is very messy, slow (involved multiple joins and 3 windows function) and it is not working in some cases. I am missing some data.

It would be great if someone can help me in the right direction on how to approach this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share us the code which you tried and try to add tables instead of pictures https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH
-- your input, don't use in final query
visits(wk,visit_id,cust_id,has_purchased) AS (
            SELECT 1,1,1,FALSE
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,1,FALSE
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,3,1,TRUE
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,1,TRUE
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
with_counter AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , LAG(CASE WHEN has_purchased THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,1,0)
    OVER(PARTITION BY wk,cust_id ORDER BY visit_id)  AS grp_end
   FROM visits
)
SELECT
  wk
, cust_id
, grp_end
, COUNT(*) AS visits_before_purchase
FROM with_counter
GROUP BY
  wk
, cust_id
, grp_end
;
-- out  wk | cust_id | grp_end | visits_before_purchase 
-- out ----+---------+---------+------------------------
-- out   1 |       1 |       0 |                      3
-- out   1 |       1 |       1 |                      1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that each the each time a customer visit, their visit id will increase by 1 each time. So I just took the difference between the visit id for each customer to find out how many visit they made before purchasing something.

```
SELECT weeks, visit_id, customer_id, purchase_flag, 
CASE WHEN diff IS null then visit_id else diff 
end
FROM (
    SELECT *, visit_id - LAG(visit_id) over (partition by customer_id  order by 
    customer_id, visit_id)as diff 
    FROM customer 
    WHERE purchase_flag = 1
   ) as t ORDER BY customer_id, visit_id
```